# Blazor - preventing navigation external and internal

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-jsinterop

I have placed in my page:

```
<NavigationLock ConfirmExternalNavigation="@changed" OnBeforeInternalNavigation="BeforeInternalNavigation" />
```

and in my code I set:

```
private bool changed = false;
```

to true at the point I want the user to be questioned about leaving the page.

This all works fine when the user tries to navigate to an external location. However, it is not working for internal navigation.

For the internal navgation event I have:

```
[Inject]
public IJSRuntime JS { get; set; }

private async Task BeforeInternalNavigation(LocationChangingContext context)
{
    if (changed)
    {
        var proceed = await JS.InvokeAsync<bool>("Confirm", "Are you sure you want to continue?");

        if (!proceed)
            context.PreventNavigation();
    }
}
```

The method gets hit as expected, but JS.InvokeAsync does not invoke the default dialog, can somone tell me where I have gone wrong please. I know I could just redirect to a custom dialog, but I want to keep it consistent with the default external dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS is case sensitive, change this

```
var proceed = await JS.InvokeAsync<bool>("Confirm", "Are you sure you want to continue?");
```

to

```
var proceed = await JS.InvokeAsync<bool>("confirm", "Are you sure you want to continue?");
```

And it should work as expected.